# Error establishing a database connection several times a week

Tags: apache2, mysql

I have a client I do web development for who had a basic low traffic WordpRess site running on Ubuntu 12.0.4 with Digitalocean.

Basic LAMP stack that they provide pre built with WordPress installed.

About 3-4 times a week, the MySQL DB goes down and shows this message on the site:

**Error establishing a database connection**

I then have to SSH into the box and reboot MySQL.  Takes all but 15 seconds however can be down for hours if I don't notice it.  It;s not fair to my client as it is random and up to 6 times a week sometimes!

I am a PHP and JavaScript developer so my Server admin skills are limited.

Please can someone assist in how I can find the problem, source of problem I should say and hopefully fix it permanently?

---

**UPDATE**

I have a log file here `/var/log/mysql.log` that has a last modified date/time around the time the MySQL server crashed today.  It is an empty file though.

Sorting files in that directory `/var/log/` by DateTime I can see one of the most recent modified files is called **syslog**

I have pasted the contents of **syslog** below as near the bottom it mentions **MySQL** so I feel it may be relevant if someone could try to help me make sense of it please?

---

**/var/log/syslog**

```
Jun 24 16:17:01 thomaslastname CRON[928]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 24 16:32:27 thomaslastname kernel: [2738822.445529] type=1400 audit(1435177947.529:25): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=1048 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jun 24 16:32:29 thomaslastname /etc/mysql/debian-start[1102]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Jun 24 16:32:29 thomaslastname /etc/mysql/debian-start[1105]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Jun 24 16:32:29 thomaslastname /etc/mysql/debian-start[1105]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Jun 24 16:32:29 thomaslastname /etc/mysql/debian-start[1105]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Jun 24 16:32:29 thomaslastname /etc/mysql/debian-start[1105]: This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.38, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
Jun 24 16:32:29 thomaslastname /etc/mysql/debian-start[1116]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Jun 24 16:32:29 thomaslastname /etc/mysql/debian-start[1122]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables
Jun 24 16:39:01 thomaslastname CRON[1208]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Jun 24 16:39:01 thomaslastname postfix/pickup[32544]: 5F48363D60: uid=0 from=<root>
Jun 24 16:39:01 thomaslastname postfix/cleanup[1221]: 5F48363D60: message-id=<20150624203901.5F48363D60@WP-NewBase-052814>
Jun 24 16:39:01 thomaslastname postfix/qmgr[1002]: 5F48363D60: from=<root@WP-NewBase-052814>, size=866, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 24 16:39:01 thomaslastname postfix/local[1223]: 5F48363D60: to=<root@WP-NewBase-052814>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jun 24 16:39:01 thomaslastname postfix/qmgr[1002]: 5F48363D60: removed
```

---

**/var/log/mysql/error.log**

```
150624 16:32:27 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150624 16:32:27 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150624 16:32:27 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150624 16:32:27 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150624 16:32:27 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150624 16:32:27 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150624 16:32:27 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150624 16:32:27 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150624 16:32:27 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 18880361123
150624 16:32:27  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 18880542657
150624 16:32:27  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
150624 16:32:27  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150624 16:32:28 InnoDB: 5.5.38 started; log sequence number 18880542657
150624 16:32:28 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
150624 16:32:28 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
150624 16:32:28 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
150624 16:32:28 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150624 16:32:28 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
150624 16:32:29 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './wordpress/wp_aiowps_login_activity' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
150624 16:32:29 [Warning] Checking table:   './wordpress/wp_aiowps_login_activity'
```

Comment: Does running `sudo service mysql restart` in a terminal restart MySQL?

Comment: Take a look at `/var/log/mysql.err`, `/var/log/mysql.log` and generally in the /var/log/ folder for more info on what the problem might be. The apache error log (  `/var/log/apache/error.log` ) might be of some help as well.

Comment: @Olathe Yes that is how I restart it everytime and it runs fines for a few days before randomly crashing again

Comment: @SledgeHammer I think I Might of found something in this `syslog` file.  I posted the contents above in my question if you might please be able to take a look?  Also just found a file here `/var/log/mysql/error.log` and posted it's contents as well

Comment: Apparently some of the tables used by WP are crashing and when you restart the MySQL server it auto-repairs them. In order to be sure whether this is a 100% the problem, you might want to install something like phpMyAdmin on the machine and the next time the site goes down, open phpmyadmin before restarting the mysql server and see whether there are crashed tables in the WP database (you should also be able to repair them from there, without a need for mysql restart). If that is the problem the only easy fix I could think of right now is some automatic database maintenance plugin for WP.

Comment: @SledgeHammer, [tables do not crash](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_crash).  After all, tables are not programs. Instead, tables are marked as 'crashed' when MySQL starts a potentially-damaging operation on them and then unmarked when MySQL finishes the operation. That way, if MySQL dies before the operation completes, the tables will stay marked so that damage from an incomplete operation can be checked for and fixed. As you can see in the log, `Database was not shut down normally!` and `Starting crash recovery.`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't enough information here to fully diagnose the connection issues. Your MySQL error log says that MySQL crashed but nothing about why.

You can continue investigating if you'd like, but there's a solution you can apply in the meantime.

## Every five minutes, automatically restart MySQL if it's not accepting connections

**Note**: this will take MySQL out of service for about six minutes.

1. Open a MySQL prompt or run a command in phpMyAdmin (choose a better alphanumeric, no-spaces password than `abcdefg`):

   ```
   CREATE USER 'hang-check'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'abcdefg';
   ```
2. Ensure that you can log in to the database as `hang-check` and that they can't see any of your WordPress databases.
3. Open a terminal on the server, and run:

   ```
   sudo -i
   EDITOR=nano crontab -e
   ```
4. In the crontab file, insert the following line (**change `abcdefg` to the password you chose earlier**), save it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>), and exit back to the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>):

   ```
    */5 * * * * /usr/bin/mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --connect_timeout=30 --user=hang-check --password='abcdefg' -e '' || (/usr/bin/killall -9 mysqld_safe mysqld; /bin/sleep 15; /usr/sbin/service mysql start)
   ```
5. Run this in the same terminal:

   ```
    sudo -i
    service mysql stop
    killall -9 mysqld_safe mysqld
    sleep 360; ps -umysql
   ```
6. Wait six minutes until it finishes.
7. Ensure that the last command responds with a line that ends with `mysqld`. If it doesn't, run `service mysql start` and comment here.
8. Close the terminal.

Comment: thanks I will try this tomorrow as my client writes articles all night